# Disminuir el timeout de intento de conexión cuando no hay internet en html

Tags: jquery, html5, timeout

Buenas!
Estoy haciendo unos cambios en la intranet de mi empresa, en un una de las paginas necesito cargar unos mapas, pero el problema que tengo es que muchas de las pc no cuentan con acceso a internet. Para esto implemente un script que encontré para verificar la conexión

en html

```
<img src="http://flickr.com/favicon.ico" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='imagencd.jpg' ;" hidden="true"></img>
```

y en mi main.js

```
var imgsrc = 'http://flickr.com/favicon.ico';
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function () {
    alert("No hay conexión a internet.");
}
img.onload = function () {
    alert("Hay conexión a internet.");
}
img.src = imgsrc;
```

Este código me funciona bien, pero para que me de el mensaje de error se queda aproximadamente 5 minutos intentado conectar a [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com)

Intente hacer

```
setTimeout(function(){
   if(img.complete){
     alert("Hay conexión a internet.");
   }else{
     alert("No hay conexión a internet.");
   }
}, 5000);
```

que me verifique si la imagen ya estaba cargada después de 5 segundos, pero se ejecuta después de los 5 minutos de espera.

Alguna idea de como cambiar el tiempo de espera para cargar la imagen??

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay una libreria llamada offlne.js puedes probarla a ver si te funciona

http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/